# Round decimal variable in stimulsoft

Tags: stimulsoft

I have 3 decimal variable in stimul soft.
i want if part of the decimal is zero round number to long
for example :

```
Var1    Var2    Var3
1.000   1.000   2.000
1.262   1.000   2.262
```

Convert To ====>

```
Var1    Var2    Var3
1       1       2

1.262   1       2.262
```

Can i use Function Rund?
if possiable how i can?

Answer (score 1):

use this code in Text :

```
{Format("{0:#.#.###}",var1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

use text Format in right click  item

for example :
[image]